# Techniques for aliasing in C#?

Tags: c#, alias

Assume i want to create an alias of a type in C# using a hypothetical syntax:

```
 Currency = float;
```

Then i go away and create a few thousand files that use `Currency` type.

Then i realize that i prefer to use FCL types:

```
 Currency = System.Single;
```

Excellent, all code still works.

*...months later...*

Wait, i'm getting some strange rounding errors. Oh that's why, [`System.Single` only has 7 digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx). Lets up that to 15 digits:

```
 Currency = System.Double;
```

*...years later...*

Ohhhh, *floating point* isn't exact; multiplying `$0.0011/unit * 217,384 units` exposes some limitations of using floating point. And accountants are sticklers against "accounting irregularities". No problem:

```
Currency = System.Decimal;
```

*...years later...*

International applications? Currency codes. Hmmmm. [Thank you CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MoneyTypeForCLR.aspx):

```
 Currency = Money;
```

*...later...*

Ooo, patterns and practices. Let's obfuscate some of that code:

```
 Currency = ICurrency;
```

And during all this nonsense code didn't break.

i know C# doesn't support this level of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) and resilency with the syntax i made up.

But can anyone suggest a syntax that can [*simulate*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302631/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-alias-with-net-type) [what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566579/using-an-alias-for-environment-newline) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214177/c-sharp-type-alias-custom-type) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394030/alias-for-int32-int64) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088824/c-sharp-public-type-alias) [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244246/c-alias-a-class-name) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844651/alias-keyword-like-typedef-in-c) [accomplish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577692/c-globally-alias-a-generic-class-name) ([including](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244246/c-alias-a-class-name) [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523568/12597))?

Comment: basically a typedef in C++ / C

Comment: I assume you know know about "using aliases"...?

Comment: I use "type aliases" ("using aliases") to make code easier to follow an consistent ... however, this sounds like a breaking change. The rules (and signature) about the type being used are altered.

Comment: Doh! *trying* and *including* link to the same question.

Comment: Looks like good example of how not to use aliases. Best I know aliases were used when you have namespace confliction or just a short name of overly long class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `using` like so: `using Currency = System.Single;`, but you must do it in every single file. But still easier to change, than searching for single in whole application.

Answer (score 5):

Create a class called Currency and implement (or delegate) the appropriate operators, then just change the class used to store the data internally when desired.